# disabled button still firing event vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a pagination that will become disable if the response is null

this is the response

```
pagination:Object
  current_page:1
  last_page:4
  next_page_url:"http://localhost/acct/public/api/businesses?page=2"
  prev_page_url:null
```

this is the pagination

```
<nav aria-label="...">
  <ul class="pager">
     <li :class="[{disabled: !pagination.prev_page_url}]" ><a href="#" @click="fetchBusiness(pagination.prev_page_url)">Previous</a></li>
     <li :class="[{disabled: !pagination.next_page_url}]" ><a href="#" @click="fetchBusiness(pagination.next_page_url)">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

the button will become disable but the event is still firing what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are adding a class which only applies visual styles. If you were really using button element, you would be able to conditionally add "disabled" attribute to element and it would disable "click" events. I'm afraid it won't work this way with "li" elements. If you want to keep you existing layout, try to change your click handlers from

```
@click="fetchBusiness(pagination.prev_page_url)"
```

to

```
@click="!!pagination.prev_page_url && fetchBusiness(pagination.prev_page_url)"
```

Answer (score 16):

For a Vue solution you can use [Event Modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers), however, if you don't need a Vue solution I'd recommend a CSS one - [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) - just add this property to the `.disabled` child element:

```
.disabled a { pointer-events: none }
```

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">foo</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="disabled">bar</a>
```

Comment: thanks, helped me a lot and the solution works in most cases: https://caniuse.com/?search=pointer-event

Comment: Anyway to achieve pointer-events none only for JS callbacks and not for :hover behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You are using vue.js, so you can use that conditions like,

```
<button v-if="pagination.prev_page_url !== null" type="button" @click="fetchBusiness(pagination.prev_page_url)">Previous</button>
<button v-else type="button" disabled>Previous</button>

<button type="button" v-if="pagination.next_page_url !== null" @click="fetchBusiness(pagination.prev_page_url)">Next</button>
<button  type="button" v-else disabled>Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition class and write CSS to prevent any click event.

```
 :class="gettingDataField && `disabled-click`"  // vue

.disabled-click { pointer-events: none }  //css
```